# Copy into Snowflake table with an additional value for a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table created, and hoping to use `copy into` command to load data from a csv file in S3.

The problem is, I want to populate the first 2 columns of the table using the data from S3, and hardcode the last column `col3` of the table with a static value `data from file 1`. How can this be done? It'd be tricky to populate `col3` after the copy into is done, because there are multiple files needs to be copied into the same table, and I hope `col3` has the vale `data from file 1`, `data from file 2` etc. Thanks.

```
create table myschema.table_test (
   col1 string, ---should be from csv file $1
   col2 string,---should be from csv file $2
   col3 string); ---should be hard coded as "data from file x.."
```

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. First copy into a staging table, then create the table by selecting staging table with an extra column

Comment: Hi - can’t you just include the hardcoded column in the COPY INTO SELECT statement?

Comment: @NickW is correct.  If you use a SELECT statement in your COPY INTO, this can be achieved in 1 step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if below helps where the `COPY INTO` command was modified to load data from `CSV` files into the first two columns of a `Snowflake` table while hardcoding a unique static value into the third column for each file to distinguish data sources.

```
  COPY INTO myschema.table_test (col1, col2, col3)
    FROM (
        SELECT $1, $2, 'data from file 1' 
        FROM @your_stage/path_to_file/file1.csv
        FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' SKIP_HEADER = 1)
    );
```